# How to specify dates before scraping in R with rvest?

Tags: r, web-scraping, datepicker, rvest

Hotel room rates vary with check-in and check-out dates. Rates scraped, therefore, should depend on the dates specified.

I'm new to web scraping, and tried to run a simple script in R to scrape the room rate of a particular hotel on TripAdvisor.

```
library(rvest)
url <- "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g60971-d75749-Reviews-Little_America_Hotel_Flagstaff-Flagstaff_Arizona.html"
page <- read_html(url)
rate <- html_nodes(page, ".bb_price_text")
print(rate)
```

The output surprised me. I got three different rates all within a span of a few minutes today, although only one of these rates ($199) is consistently shown online when I access the URL using a browser (amount displayed online with a strikethrough is $216).

```
#{xml_nodeset (1)}
#[1] <div class="bb_price_text  hasStrikeThrough">$189</div>

#{xml_nodeset (1)}
#[1] <div class="bb_price_text  hasStrikeThrough ">$199</div>

#{xml_nodeset (1)}
#[1] <div class="bb_price_text ">$259</div>
```

I’m guessing that the different rates correspond to different check-in and check-out dates. To know which dates corresponded to the rate being scraped, I executed the following code.

```
dates <- html_nodes(page, ".picker-count")
print(dates)
```

This returned May 29 and May 30.

```
#{xml_nodeset (2)}
#[1] <span class="picker-count">May 29</span>
#[2] <span class="picker-count">May 30</span>
```

The fact that three different rates show up means that the script is cycling through three different sets of check-in and check-out dates. How? Is it possible to set these dates programmatically in R before scraping?

Any insight or help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Though I don't know how to change the dates yet. The price difference is not due to the difference in dates. I tested that webpage using random user agent and random proxy. And it gives me different prices.

So it could possibly be either TripAdvisor's price discrimination or AB testing.

Comment: I wouldn't invalidate the difference in dates as one of the possible causes of the difference in prices. The output in one instance of running the script shows that the different room rate accompanied a different set of check-in and check-out dates: > page <- read_html(url)
> rate <- html_nodes(page, ".bb_price_text")
> print(rate)
{xml_nodeset (1)}
[1] <div class="bb_price_text  hasStrikeThrough">$189</div> 
> dates <- html_nodes(page, ".picker-count")
> print(dates)
{xml_nodeset (2)}
[1] <span class="picker-count">May 28</span>
[2] <span class="picker-count">May 29</span>

Comment: Websites with too many interactive values can be very hard to parse using rvest. I suggest you using Rselenium as an alternative. It supports simulations with mouse clicks and key presses. So you can simulate clicking on different dates.